# How to efficiently compute the maximum value of a collection after applying some function

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose you have a method like this that computes the maximum of a `Collection` for some `ToIntFunction`:

```
static <T> void foo1(Collection<? extends T> collection, ToIntFunction<? super T> function) {
    if (collection.isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    T maxT = null;
    for (T t : collection) {
        int result = function.applyAsInt(t);
        if (result >= max) {
            max = result;
            maxT = t;
        }
    }
    // do something with maxT
}
```

With Java 8, this could be translated into

```
static <T> void foo2(Collection<? extends T> collection, ToIntFunction<? super T> function) {
    T maxT = collection.stream()
                       .max(Comparator.comparingInt(function))
                       .get();
    // do something with maxT
}
```

A disadvantage with the new version is that `function.applyAsInt` is invoked repeatedly for the same value of `T`. (Specifically if the collection has size `n`, `foo1` invokes `applyAsInt` `n` times whereas `foo2` invokes it `2n - 2` times).

Disadvantages of the first approach are that the code is less clear and you can't modify it to use parallelism.

Suppose you wanted to do this using parallel streams **and** only invoke `applyAsInt` once per element. Can this be written in a simple way?

Comment: I would come up with an intermediate datastructure like `Pair<T, int>`. Map the `T` value to the structure, sort it and then find the maximum.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me why in the second method it is invoked 2n - 2 times ? Can you enlight me please ?

Comment: Suppose list is (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and 1 is the biggest. foo2 compares 1 with 2, then 1 with 3, then 1 with 4, then 1 with 5. Each time you compare 1 with something you need to call applyAsInt. In general if there are n elements, there will be n - 1 comparisons. Since each comparison calls the method on 2 elements, it's 2n - 2.

Comment: @user2336315 The easiest way to check is to make `applyAsInt` increment some `counter` field. You can see that this happens.

Comment: This is not true, as the max here is a regular reduction operation

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy What is not true?

Comment: @PaulBoddington what is not true is the foo2 takes `2n - 2`, the `max` here is a special case of `reduce` operation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: @PaulBoddington I think you're right it's applied 2n-2 times but not this way. In your example, it will compare 1 with 2, then 2 with 3, then 3 with 4, then 4 with 5 (for a sequential pipeline of course).

Comment: @user2336315 You might be right, but the important thing is it's 4 comparisons, so 8 applyAsInt calls.

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy No, Paul is right, it is applied 2n-2 times because to compare the elements, you must apply the function. So you will apply the function 2 times for the same element. When you reduce `a, b, c`, you will compare `f(a) f(b)` and `f(b) f(c)`, so 4 times = 2*3-2.

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy https://ideone.com/3923a8

Comment: Actually it is not `2n - 2`, it is exactly `(n-1) * 2`

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy Hmm, isn't `2 * (n - 1) = 2n - 2`? :D

Comment: Yea, but i want to show the way it is computed

Comment: Don't call `get()`, call one of the safe methods like `orElse()`, `ifPresent()`, etc.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: in this case, calling `get()` is justified as it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` when empty, just like the original method of the question does when the `Collection` is empty and like [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) does in the same case…

Comment: @Holger I respectfully disagree.  Much better to use .orElseThrow(...) to make this explicit.  Same effect, but far more obvious what is going on.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: a `throws NoSuchElementException` at the method would do the same. Or keeping the `if(collection.isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();` at the method start (which looks even cleaner to me).

Comment: @Holger Problem is, you've already done 100x more analysis in trying to defend against my suggestion than most people will do when looking at (or writing) code that involves `Optional::get`.  Given that the WHOLE POINT of adding `Optional` to the APIs was to make it harder to have unexpected NPEs by making it more explicit, reintroducing unexpected implicit exceptions via the harmlessly-named `get()` really undermines the point.  Mea culpa for having picked this name -- IMO our biggest mistake of Java 8 -- but we should at least do our best to avoid making it worse.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: since I would use `Collections.max` here, I have no choice anyway. Any plans to augment these methods with an alternative returning an `Optional`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a custom collector that keeps running pair of the maximum value and the maximum element:

```
static <T> void foo3(Collection<? extends T> collection, ToIntFunction<? super T> function) {
    class Pair {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        T maxT = null;
    }
    T maxT = collection.stream().collect(Collector.of(
        Pair::new,
        (p, t) -> {
            int result = function.applyAsInt(t);
            if (result >= p.max) {
                p.max = result;
                p.maxT = t;
            }
        }, 
        (p1, p2) -> p2.max > p1.max ? p2 : p1,
        p -> p.maxT
    ));
    // do something with maxT
}
```

One advantage is that this creates a single `Pair` intermediate object that is used through-out the collecting process. Each time an element is accepted, this holder is updated with the new maximum. The finisher operation just returns the maximum element and disgards the maximum value.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that if you run this in parallel you'll get more than one `Pair` object instantiated.

Comment: You might want to use `if (result >= p.max)` instead of `if (result > p.max)`. Otherwise you end up with `null` in the (admittedly unlikely) event that all of the elements actually map to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Alternatively, you can use `Integer max = null;` and `if (p.max == null || result > p.max)`.

Comment: @ruakh Ha yes thanks! That's a very interesting comment. I edited with that.

Comment: @ruakh That comment also applies to the question. Really good point. I'll edit.

Comment: Using `>=` has the disadvantage of not returning the first maximum value, if there are multiple occurrences. Might be irrelevant for the specific use case, but it’s not doing the same as the original `Stream.max`. If you want to avoid the boxing to `Integer`, you could also use `long max=Long.MIN_VALUE;`, I doubt that using long comparison instead of int comparison has any performance impact and the result still will be `T`.

Answer (score 3):

As I stated in the comments I would suggest introducing an intermediate datastructure like:

```
static <T> void foo2(Collection<? extends T> collection, ToIntFunction<? super T> function) {
  if (collection.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  class Pair {
    final T value;
    final int result;

    public Pair(T value, int result) {
      this.value = value;
      this.result = result;
    }

    public T getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public int getResult() {
      return result;
    }
  }
  T maxT = collection.stream().map(t -> new Pair(t, function.applyAsInt(t)))
                     .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Pair::getResult)).get().getValue();
  // do something with maxT
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use a [memoized version of `function`](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization):

```
static <T> void foo2(Collection<? extends T> collection, 
    ToIntFunction<? super T> function, T defaultValue) {

    T maxT = collection.parallelStream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(ToIntMemoizer.memoize(function)))
        .orElse(defaultValue);

    // do something with maxT

}
```

Where `ToIntMemoizer.memoize(function)` code would be as follows:

```
public class ToIntMemoizer<T> {

    private final Map<T, Integer> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private ToIntMemoizer() {
    }

    private ToIntFunction<T> doMemoize(ToIntFunction<T> function) {
        return input -> cache.computeIfAbsent(input, function::apply);
    }

    public static <T> ToIntFunction<T> memoize(ToIntFunction<T> function) {
        return new ToIntMemoizer<T>().doMemoize(function);
    }
}
```

This uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` to cache already computed results. If you don't need to support parallelism, you can perfectly use a `HashMap`.

One disadvantage is that the result of the function needs to be boxed/unboxed. On the other hand, as the function is memoized, a result will be computed only once for each repeated element of the collection. Then, if the function is invoked with a repeated input value, the result will be returned from the cache.

Comment: I guess, boxing is not the most problematic thing here. CHM has quite a big overhead, so you will need really slow `ToIntFunction` to overweigh it. Not to mention additional memory.

Comment: @TagirValeev I totally agree. This approach only makes sense when the function is quite slow, which should be the case, since the question explicitly specifies that the stream is parallel. It should also make sense if the list contains many repeated elements and the function is not super fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using third-party library, my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) optimizes all these cases in special methods like [`maxByInt`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#maxByInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and so on. So you can simply use:

```
static <T> void foo3(Collection<? extends T> collection, ToIntFunction<? super T> function) {
    T maxT = StreamEx.of(collection).parallel()
                       .maxByInt(function)
                       .get();
    // do something with maxT
}
```

The [implementation](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/57e9c2387e0f9a8f98a909761ccd66202b55bb0c/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.java#L989) uses `reduce` with mutable container. This probably abuses API a little, but works fine for sequential and parallel streams and unlike `collect` solution defers the container allocation to the first accumulated element (thus no container is allocated if parallel subtask covers no elements which occurs quite often if you have the filtering operation upstream).